# Vuex plugin error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        user: {
            userName:'',
            loggedInStatus: true,
            authToken: ''
        }
    },

    mutations: {
        addWebToken: function(state, webToken){
            state.user.authToken = webToken;
        },
        removeWebToken: function(state){
            state.user.authToken = '';
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getToken:function (){
            return  store.state.user.authToken;

        }
    },
    plugins: [createPersistedState()]

})
```

I have included "vuex-persistedstate.js" but it shows errors in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'default' in undefined
  at vuex-persistedstate.js:17

Uncaught ReferenceError: createPersistedState is not defined
```

When I ctrl + click on createPersistedState() call I can navigate to that file.

Comment: Did you try including it without the `.js` extension. Not sure that it would make a difference, but I assume that if the module is inside node_modules, then doing `import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'` should include its `index.js` file instead of whatever it would try to load otherwise. That would probably also explain why `createPersistedState is not defined` - it probably couldn't find it because it was looking for the wrong thing.

Comment: I am not using node,npm. I am using plain js.

Comment: I am not sure but it seems to me that the plugin is built with npm in mind. If you look at the [source](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/blob/master/dist/vuex-persistedstate.js) it seems to me like it's built to be used within a framework that supports imports/require. Look at lines 12-15.

Answer (score 1):

vuex-persistedstate.js need dependency on lodash and object-path. This 
error on vuex-persistedstate.js line 17, is the missing lodash dependency.
If you already added lodash, make sure it's loaded inside the vuex-persistedstate module.

If you really want using plain js. You have to define `window.merge = _.merge` and `window.objectPath` have to be define with correct node module. You rather use webpack to use correctly this npm module.

More source : https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/23